# Make separate header file classes aware of each other

Tags: c++, class

Right now I have the following files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    mirage a;
    inferno b;
    b.do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

**file1.h**

```
#ifndef FILE1_H_
#define FILE1_H_
class mirage{
    int collect;
    void setup();
}
#endif
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include "file1.h"

void mirage::setup(){
    collect = 2;
}
```

**file2.h**

```
#ifndef FILE2_H_
#define FILE2_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class inferno{
    void print_out();
}
#endif
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "file2.h"

void inferno::print_out(){
    cout << a.collect << endl;
}
```

My goal is to be able to reference the mirage class from a function inside the infero class function.  How right now, i get a compile error stating that "file2.cpp:4: error 'a' was not declared in this scope".  How do I make the inferno class aware of the mirage class without re-declaring it in the scope of file2?

Comment: In your second example, do you mean file1.cpp?

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like, you just want to be able to use the `mirage` class within the `inferno` class operations.

To do this, simply include the header file containing the declaration of the `mirage` class (`file1.h`) in your `file2.h`. This is give you access to the `mirage` class declaration and operations for operations within the `inferno` class.

However, for using an object within the `print_out` method of the `inferno` class, you need a parameter for the method to access an object of the `mirage` type. Simply change the prototype in the `inferno` class header to:

```
void print_out(const mirage &m);
```

...and the stub in the .cpp file to...

```
void inferno::print_out(const mirage &m)
{
    cout << m.collect << endl;
}
```

So the overall, the changes to be made are:

**file2.h**

```
#ifndef FILE2_H_
#define FILE2_H_
#include <iostream>
#include "file1.h"

using namespace std;

class inferno{
    void print_out(const mirage &m);
}
#endif
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "file2.h"

void inferno::print_out(const mirage &m){
    cout << m.collect << endl;
}
```

Comment: @PaulRooney yes I am aware, with a question as basic as this is didn't know the experience of the asker so I kept the parameter simple. I did originally have them types as `const mirage &m` but decided not to haha

Answer (score 0):

The error is because 'a'  is not defined anywhere.

What I believe you want is for a to be a `mirage` object that you can reference from `inferno`. There are three techniques you can use to do this.

The first is a HAS-A object relationship. If you define an instance variable in `inferno` that you assign a `mirage` object to, then you can manipulate and reference that object from within the `inferno` class. In this case, the `inferno` class owns (or in other words, has a) `mirage` object.

The other option is using inheritance so that the `inferno` object IS-A `mirage` object. This allows a child object (`inferno`) to access the instance variables and methods of the parent object (`mirage`). An example of this type of relationship is a shape and a square object. A shape may have attribute like name, position, and colour. A square IS-A shape, meaning it will inherit the name, position, and colour attributes, but will also define it's own attributed like side length.

For more information, look up class inheritance, IS-A and HAS-A class relationships, and Object Oriented programming.

The last option is to simply pass in the `mirage` object as a parameter to the `inferno` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference mirage a in file2.cpp without declaration, because mirage a is only visible in main function. You can make it a global variable if you want to do it.